# HTTPError: 403 Forbidden PYPI ERROR - Username/Password authentication is no longer supported. Migrate to API Tokens or Trusted Publishers instead

Tags: python, github-actions, pypi

I have a python package that uses this github action to upload new versions to pypi (https://github.com/PythonNest/PyNest/blob/main/.github/workflows/release.yaml)
it seems that pypi is no longer accept using username and password as the combination to authenticate yourself to pypi.

this is the full error I'm getting -

```
WARNING  Error during upload. Retry with the --verbose option for more details. 
ERROR    HTTPError: 403 Forbidden from https://upload.pypi.org/legacy/          
         Username/Password authentication is no longer supported. Migrate to API
         Tokens or Trusted Publishers instead. See                              
         https://pypi.org/help/#apitoken and                                    
         https://pypi.org/help/#trusted-publishers                              
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

So I went to the Pypi site to check what I could do. I've configured 2FA.
i went to the API tokens sections and I see that I have them, and also, I'm using them as part of my CI, since my `username = "__token__"` and my password is "pypi-token.....", which is, from what I know, is how things done. is there a way to use `twine upload` with the token?

any idea how I can overcome this? it's really holding me from publishing new versions

Comment: I would double-check your username and password values, but primarily, it would be easier to switch to the trusted publisher system and to use the official upload GHA action (see [example here](https://github.com/python-babel/babel/pull/1028/commits/d8dc87b79eb92128be5924bf7d9869ee965a641f)).

Comment: Thank you! it seems that I've needed to create a new token.

Comment: Hey ItayDar! Can you tell me how you did that? I am stuck there for a bit now :\

Answer (score -1):

python -m twine upload -u USERNAME -p PASSWORD dist/*

Or

**use it at first pririty:**
python -m twine upload -u __token__ -p [unique_token] dist/*